# C# Connecting to Oracle database, Oracle.Data.Access not found on client computer

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have problem with my C# app connecting to database through through Oracle.Data.Access.
Of course program is working on my (develop) computer, but doesnt work on my friend's pc.
I have installed ODAC Xcopy and Oracle Instant Client (12) on his computer also added into system variables PATH.
When Im trying to run it I got "not found OraOps12.dll" problem.
Anybody know whats wrong?
Should I install something else?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is OraOps12.dll on your friends computer? Is it referenced in your app.config, and if so what location is referenced for it?

Comment: Yes, that dll is in Oracle Client folder, which is added into PATH.
In app,config there is no any dlls mentioned, only my variables and Framework version

Comment: If you can, use the managed driver. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/ 
you don't need any file except this one.  no instant client

Comment: Yes I know about that, but my app has 8 forms and about 6 database connections ech. So I prefer to find out what I have to install than changing a lot of code, but thanks for advice

Comment: EDIT: Installed normal version of ODAC (not  XCopy) and it works

Comment: Did you simply copy over the xcopy package or did you run the .bat file that comes with it?  See http://www.brothersincode.com/post/Oracle-ODPnet-xcopy-deployment-for-aspnet.aspx

Comment: I run "configure" file and it doesnt work, maybe I did something wrong, but normal instalation version works good and my problem is solved :)